# Not able to trace C++ leaks with instruments

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using C++ in my objective-c app and doing the following allocations in the scene:

```
@interface Game1PlayerLayer : CCLayer {

    b2World *_world;
    GLESDebugDraw *_debugDraw;
    MyContactListener *_contactListener;
}

+(CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

In implementation I allocate:

```
_world = new b2World(gravity);
_debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);
_contactListener = new MyContactListener();
```

Of course I have to deallocate them with

```
delete _world;
delete _debugDraw;
delete _contactListener;
```

But if I am not deleting them, Xcode Leaks instrument doesn't show those leaks. I certainly checked that deallocation of `Game1PlayerLayer` took place. Leaks instrument set to 1 second snapshot. If Xcode is capable to show C++ leaks, what should I do to track them?

Answer (score 0):

How about avoiding the whole issue and using `std::shared_ptr` instead?

```
@interface Game1PlayerLayer : CCLayer {

    std::shared_ptr<b2World> _world;
    std::shared_ptr<GLESDebugDraw> _debugDraw;
    std::shared_ptr<MyContactListener> _contactListener;
}


_world.reset(new b2World(gravity));
_debugDraw.reset(new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO));
_contactListener.reset(new MyContactListener());


#if 0
delete _world;
delete _debugDraw;
delete _contactListener;
#endif
```

Comment: "Avoiding issue" means I don't have to check leaks for C++ objects or the leaks will be shown correctly in Instruments?

Comment: @Pablo It means you shouldn't have to worry about it at all.  Pass the pointers around as `std::shared_ptr<X>` and you should be assured it cannot leak.

Comment: Looks not easy to integrate boost library into Xcode project :) Many reported dozens of errors and none reported success stories (from what I've seen so far) :) Will keep digging but if you could briefly tell from where to download (macports/sources) and whether to use build static library and link or to include sources into project?

Comment: @Pablo It's part of the standard library (you probably want `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++`, depending on your deployment target).

Comment: OK, plz bear with me :) I did `#import <tr1/boost_shared_ptr.h>` in my header file. Then in `LLVM 5.0 C++ Language Dialect` I set `-std=c++11` and in `C++ Standard Library` I set `libstdc++`. I've got dozens of compiler errors such as `No member named '_Lock_policy in namespace '__gnu_cxx'.

Comment: Just `#import <memory>` and use as described above.

Comment: Still no luck but now errors in my header file. No type named 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' on `std::shared_ptr<b2World> _world;` and other two.

Comment: @Pablo I don't know what else to tell you; check your compiler options (as mentioned above) and `#import <memory>`.  If you have any non-Objective-C++ code then that will be an issue and you have to ensure Objective-C doesn't see C++.